# how to plot multiple polygon plots in R?

Tags: r, polygon

I am plotting polygon using R

```
yy<-c(1217,2343,3255,2129)
xx<-c(61587690.5,61588253.5,61587797.5,61587234.5)
polygon(xx, yy, col="gray", border = "red")
```

But i want to add 100000 polygon plots to the same chart. How can i add all into one chart.

---

---

Comment: You just call polygon again. How are your data structured?

Comment: I opened a complementary question that might be complementary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138199/r-base-graphics-control-the-drawing-order-of-multiple-polygons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using a list of lists of coordinates. It plots all polygons in the same plot (I leave the question of how discernible they are to you...)

```
#generate some data
set.seed(123)
n=10
#each 'polygon' is inside a list with xx and yy coordinates
dat <- lapply(1:n,function(x){
  res <- list(xx=c(1,2,3,2)+rnorm(4),
              yy=c(1,2,3,2)+rnorm(4))
  return(res)
})

#create empty plot
plot(0:5,0:5,type='n')
#add polygons
lapply(dat,function(x){polygon(x$xx,x$yy,col="gray",border="red")})
```

[image]

Comment: but above plot is not completely printed. Do i need to set x and y axis limit?

Comment: Yes. It's an example, based on simulated data. @logicstar

Comment: @jogo I did not mean to 'hide a forloop', I meant to provide code that's scalable and an example of a possble data-structure (as OP wanted to plot a lot of polygons). A for-loop will also work here.

Comment: For completeness, here's an example of how the "for loop" suggested by @jogo and using the example data provided by @Heroka would work. Just replace the command starting by `lapply` by the following line: `for (i in 1:n) polygon(unlist(dat[[i]]$xx,dat[[i]]$yy),col="gray",border="red")`

Answer (score 3):

for 2 polygons:

```
yy<-c(1217,2343,3255,2129)
xx<-c(61587690.5,61588253.5,61587797.5,61587234.5)
plot(xx,yy, type='n')
# plot(0,0, type='n', xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim=c(-200, 100)) # an other plot region
polygon(xx, yy, col="gray", border = "red")
xx <- xx+500
yy <- yy+500
polygon(xx, yy, col="gray", border = "red")
```

Comment: This is not doable for 100000 polygons.

Comment: theoretical one can do it in a for-loop. But I dont know if that is the desired result.

Comment: @jogo it is ok for me but i found IInd polygon is not visible completely. Do i need to set any x limt or/and y limit.

Comment: yes, the plot region is defined per parameters of `plot()`. read the documentation. `plot(0,0, xlim=c(-5, 5), ylim=c(-200, 100))`