# How to add lines to existing plot in R?

Tags: r, line

This refers to my previous question.

[how to plot multiple polygon plots in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524037/how-to-plot-multiple-polygon-plots-in-r)

How can i add lines (not segments) to existing plot(with polygon) which has diamond at its each terminal.

Comment: Which kind of line? (x,y) coordinates? Constant? What?

Comment: Yes i have start(x,y) and stop(x,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lines` for this:

```
#random plot
plot(1:10, xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0,10))
#then plot line with x1,x2 and y1,y2 co-ordinates 
#below x1=0 x2=5 y1=2 and y2=8
lines(c(0, 5), c(2, 8), type='l')
```

Make sure you add `xlim` and `ylim` in `plot` in order for `lines` to pick up the correct scale.

[image]